# How to exclude some domain or IP address from proxy on Google Chrome for Linux(Fedora)?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, proxy, fedora

I set proxy server to Fedora.

I do not want to use proxy when access to some IP address by Google Chrome for Linux(Fedora).

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to chrome settings [or type chrome://settings/ on address bar] the click on show advanced settings link at the bottom.

Click on the change proxy settings button under Network section.
It will pop up a window (it is the system "Network proxy preferences" window). Click on the ignored hosts tab and add the IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

The Fedora Network Proxy window does not include an ignore list. Instead, visit

> Applications >  System Tools > dconf Editor.

Within the editor, go to

> system > proxy

and edit the `ignore-hosts` value by adding the relative IPs/domains